# MathJax stops working once the js cached in the browser

Tags: javascript, html, caching, mathjax

I have this formula: ({\Delta ^{ - 1}} - T{V_0})

It works perfectly fine when I open the 1st the webpage. As soon as i refresh or open it again, the formula is diplayed in it raw format.

When I remove the browser cache, it work again the next time.

Any idea?

I have tried with Firefox, Chrome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help Davide, but I figured out what the problem was. In fact, one part of the page was loaded with Ajax, so mathjax was running before the page was loaded. What happened from time to time, is that when I cleared the cache, the ajax page was loaded a bit earlier that the mathjax script, so it worked. What I did is that I reloaded mathjax once the ajax page was loaded and everything works as a charm.

```
MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub]);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have in-lne configuration, make sure it is *before* the script tag that loads MathJax.js itself.  If it comes after, MathJax may not be able to locate it when it needs it.  This can happen when MathJax is in cache, as MathJax can get to the point where it looks for the configuration earlier, and the configuration block might not be available in the DOM yet.  So make sure it comes first, as [documented](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/configuration.html#using-in-line-configuration-options).